# Reading file returns not whole row

Tags: python, file, loops

I get a behaviour by iterating through a file which I cannot explain.

```
with open("processed.txt", "r") as processed:
    next(processed)
    for row in processed:
        processedList = row.split("\t")
        print processedList
        noi = processedList[0]
        area = processedList[2]
```

That gives me the error "List index out of range".
The output of `print processedList` where the error occurs is

```
    [´ 2444´, ´´]
```

However, when I go into my file `processed.txt` and check the corresponding row which causes the error I have this:

```
2444    13876839.0465   4.5976656692    567919.110661   Dies und Das
```

How comes that?

Comment: if this is your actual code, you should indent it

Comment: The example line you provided is not seperated by tabulators, but by 3 spaces each. Is that an artefact of you posting this here? Can you verify the delimiter is in fact a `\t`?

Comment: Also, your code has typos like in line 6 where there is a c too much. Please edit the code provided to properly reflect your actual code so we can help you more easily

Comment: sorry, I did not copy and paste it but typed it manually since not everything in the for loop is of further interest. Yes, its septerated by tabs although it is displayed here differently. a couple of lines above I write that file and its written with `\t` to seperate the elements. I double checked the file `processed.txt` as well.

Comment: I just tested your example and it works OK for me. Maybe there is something in your loop that corrupts `processedList` data, or maybe this is problem in your input data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python processtext.py
['26384   13876839.0465   4.59700590692   637919.110661   Sport und Freizeitanlagen\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 7, in <module>
    area = processedList[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

in your code, every row processed as a single element list. so it is natural that processedList[2] raises `IndexError`.

I edited it as this.

```
with open("pr.txt", "r") as processed:
    processed.next()
    for row in processed:

        row = row.split()

        print row
        noi = row[0]
        area = row[2]
        print noi
        print area
```

output

```
$ python processtext.py
['23456', '134567.678900', '23456.5678909', '4567878.54566', 'Fremd', 'und', 'Geheimnsvoll']
23456
23456.5678909



#pr.txt (2 tabs (1 tab = 2 space))
23456   134567.678900   23456.5678909   4567878.54566   Fremd und Geheimnsvoll
```

Comment: nope. It reads all the `rows` before without any problem...
When I use `split()` on the row, it creates a list for each row, seperated by my delimiter. That works perfectly before but not here...

Answer (score 0):

I just copy-pasted your code and your example "processed.txt". 
After changing the 3 spaces to a tab it runs fine for me and does not produce an error. 
Since `print processedList` does not print the whole line, I suspect that there is something other than `\t` between `23456` and `134567.678900` in `processed.txt`; maybe a `\0`?

Comment: interestingely enough your code also works for @wanderlust; something strange's going on ...

Comment: Yes. Thats why I came here!

Comment: I stil think that the issue's with the text file, not with the code; can you make (a partial) processed.txt available for download somewhere, so that we can test with your data, instead of creating our own, which apparently differs in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it looks a lot like the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) built-in module could do what you want in a cleaner way.

For example:

```
import csv
with open("processed.txt", "r") as processed:
    csvreader = csv.reader(processed, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csvreader:
        processedList = row
        print processedList
        noi = processedList[0]
        area = processedList[2]
```